# implementacion duplicada en TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy programando con typescript y active el comando `tsc -w test.ts` que genera el archivo javascript a traves del archivo typescript.

Mi problema surge cuando creo la clase User y la funcion login que me salta el siguiente error:

> "function login(): void (+1 overload)
> Implementación de función duplicada.ts(2393)"

Adjunto el código typescript:

```
    class User {
        name: string;
        password: string;
    };
    
    function login(){
        var userName = (document.getElementById('user') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        var userPswd = (document.getElementById('password') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        console.log(userName);
        console.log(userPswd);
    };
```

Comment: En algún otro sitio tienes que tener declarada una función `login`

Comment: Si, en el archivo js que typescript genera automaticamente. Por eso mi duda es como evitar este error.

Comment: La única forma que vi para evitarlo es cerrar el archivo .js